# Error installing karma with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am going to install karma in my front end to run some TDD tests.
To do this at the first step i run this:

```
sudo npm install -D karma-jasmine karma-phantomjs-launcher --save
```

and it seems to me that every thing is fun, here is the result:

```
npm WARN package.json taksi_client@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json taksi_client@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json taksi_client@1.0.0 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-phantomjs-launcher
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-phantomjs-launcher
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
karma-jasmine@0.3.6 node_modules/karma-jasmine

karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.1 node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher
└── lodash@3.10.1
```

and then I ried this command

```
sudo npm install -g karma --save
```

but i get the following erorrs. and i do not know how can i fix it?

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EROFS, unlink '/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/karma'
npm ERR! error rolling back  karma@0.13.15 { [Error: EROFS, unlink '/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/karma']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 56,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EROFS',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/karma' }
npm ERR! Error: EROFS, unlink '/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/karma'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.2.0-c9
npm ERR! command "/nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/bin/node" "/mnt/shared/sbin/npm" "install" "-g" "karma" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/Taxi_Driver/taksi_client
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /nix/store/a5ibcbcsm473kdr75kj4gpsr28ndnknp-nodejs-0.10.26/lib/node_modules/karma
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno 56
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/Taxi_Driver/taksi_client/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: check if you have read and write permissions in node_module global folder

Comment: what OS? If unix-like just surf to the folder parent (cd /you/folder/parent/path) and ls -lt to see the permissions also. It should have at least write and read permissions.

Comment: try `sudo npm install -g karma` (without  `--save`)